# Inserting a multiline PHP string into a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ace-editor

**My question**
My question is about correctly parsing HTML from php into a variable inside of a javascript object (which in this case is ace-editor's value variable)

**My problem**

I have got a textarea for HTML and CSS, the HTML gets retrieved from the database and needs to be inserted into a field of croppie, i am currently using PHP's [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) functionality to put it inside of the variable, but it seems to still escape from the value.

**My code**

```
<?php

        $css = ($modify) ? trim($template->style()) : "";
        $html = ($modify) ? trim( $template->html() ) : "";

        $html = json_encode($html);
        $css = json_encode($css);


    ?>
YUI().use(
        'aui-ace-editor',
        function(Y) {
            var editorhtml = new Y.AceEditor({
                boundingBox: '#editor-html',
                height: '400',
                mode: 'html',
                value: '<?php echo substr( $html, 1, -1 ); ?>',
                width: '100%',
                showPrintMargin: false
            }).render();

            var editorcss = new Y.AceEditor({
                boundingBox: '#editor-css',
                height: '400',
                mode: 'css',
                value: '<?php echo substr( $css, 1, -1 ); ?>',
                width: '100%',
                showPrintMargin: false
            }).render();
        }
    );
```

**What happens**
When i use this, and open up a specific template which can be managed, i will not be able to see the textarea's (because the ace editor could not be loaded), i get random errors relating to line 666 which is the exact line the HTML gets stored in. I did sanitize the outputs in json_encode correctly.. right?

[image: Screenshot of html inserted into page]

in this screenshot, you can see the HTML/css which gets inserted. But the problem occurs on line 666 which the HTML is located at.
 [Click here if the screenshot isn't readable for you](https://hastebin.com/upuqobuwid.xml)

**So my question is..**

Why exactly does it not parse the HTML into the object correctly? Am i not sanitizing it correctly or am i missing something?

Comment: Your issue is because your `$html` string contains single quotes, try escaping them or using double quotes

Comment: bm_i Thank you very much, if you're willing to post this as an answer, i will accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because your `$html` string contains single quotes, try escaping them or using double quotes

Answer (score 2):

You are breaking the output of json_encode by changing double quotes it creates to single quotes.

It's better to call json_encode directly when adding value to the script tag:

```
value: <?php echo json_encode($html); ?>,
```